# movie2avi And Surf Plots

Tags: matlab

I'm currently trying to produce an avi file from 1000 small surf plots. To do this I use getframe and then movie2avi. These plots are very simple, essentially just concentric circles in one just shades of red with some light interpolated shading on them and I only want the view of them from view(0,90) in my avi. Doing this makes an avi file of resolution 436 by 344.

However, this 16 second long, low resolution file, with no GB only R is 50GB! I've tried using cinepak compression, but this barely brings the size down at all, and makes the image almost impossible to see and incredibly blurry.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This is not in anyway a duplicate to that question. The question linked is asking just how to make a video, and answers have been such as use movie2avi.

I am using movie2avi and I have a video made, it is just much larger than it should be.

Comment: I've linked you to the duplicate so that you can see whether or not what you coded agrees with what is seen in the duplicate.  You haven't shown us anything you've tried - only commented about the quality of your video and what you should be expecting.  If you update your post to include any relevant code so that your problem is reproducible, I'll reopen your post.  Until then, I'm leaving it closed... if it weren't for my duplicate vote, this would have been closed anyway because your current problem is not reproducible by any of us.

Comment: Simple answer: don't use the ancient and deprecated `movie2avi`. Use `VideoWriter` and choose a codec appropriate to your content.